# Why does Golang say my GOPATH isn't set when I set it the command directly before?

Tags: go

This is becoming very frustrating. I set my GOPATH in my `~/.bash_profile`, but Go still says it's not set. So I set it manually, and it still says.

```
computer:~ doug$ export GOPATH=~/Dropbox/golang
computer:~ doug$ sudo go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/...
package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/...: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

What am I doing wrong here? If I type `goenv` it even lists it as being set to the right path.

Comment: `sudo` changes your environment, meaning `GOPATH` is no longer exported. Run the command again without `sudo` (this is standard practice).

Comment: @TimCooper But then I get a bunch of "permission denied" errors

Comment: If you must use `sudo`, try: `sudo env GOPATH=~/Dropbox/golang go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/...` — the `env` command adds to the environment (when invoked like this) and then runs the `go` command you originally intended — but it all happens after `sudo` tinkers with the environment.  Obviously, this assumes `sudo` allows you to run `env`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` removes environment variables by default, so the command running as `root` can't see the environment variable set as `doug`. In general you shouldn't need `sudo` to run `go get`, although some of the `golang.org/x/tools` packages are somewhat special. Try installing just the ones you need (without sudo) instead of using `...`

Comment: I get a bunch of permission denied errors if I don't run it as sudo. I'm following [this tutorial](http://marcio.io/2015/07/supercharging-atom-editor-for-go-development/) which says to do that command under "Installing Packages".

Comment: Yes, some of the packages under `tools/...` need special permissions, but if you installed go correctly you should already have them. You need to identify which tools you need but don't have and only install those. (That tutorial recommends installing `...` because the author presumably installed go in a way that doesn't require root permissions, probably via homebrew).

Answer (score 1):

I especially like about go that its entire environment is particularly easy to setup just with `wget` and `tar` and **without the need for any special permissions**.

This is how I usually install (and update) go on any system:

```
$ wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.6.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
$ tar -xzvf go1.6.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
$ export GOROOT=$PWD/go
$ export PATH=$PWD/go/bin:$PATH
$ which go
/tmp/example/go/bin/go
$ go version
go version go1.6.2 linux/amd64
```

You can find the links to the tar archives here: https://golang.org/dl/

I like to download and extract each version I use to `$HOME/Programs` and then just set a symlink to point to the one I actually want to use:

```
ls -la /home/fgrosse/Programs | grep go
lrwxrwxrwx   1 fgrosse fgrosse    6 Mar  9 20:52 go -> go1.6.1
drwxr-xr-x  11 fgrosse fgrosse 4.0K Feb 17 21:47 go1.5.4
drwxr-xr-x  11 fgrosse fgrosse 4.0K Feb 17 21:47 go1.6
drwxrwxr-x  11 fgrosse fgrosse 4.0K Apr 23 19:58 go1.6.1
drwxrwxr-x  11 fgrosse fgrosse 4.0K Apr 23 19:58 go1.6.2
$ echo $GOROOT
/home/fgrosse/Programs/go
```